# How to send a percentage of transaction amount to Paypal account on Wix?

Tags: paypal, payment, velo

I'd like to automatically take a percentage of each sale and send it to a PayPal account (donation). I've been looking for a Wix app to do it, but no success there. Is the only way to do it writing custom code?

Comment: Ask Wix, they have their own support and will be familiar with what they offer and any available plugins. If there's nothing built already then yes you'll need something custom.  PayPal supports multiple `purchase_units` as part of a checkout, which will show as separate transactions to separate receivers in PayPal.com

Comment: thanks, you're right I'll try Wix support